# Can I include a forms value into the action redirect in php?

Tags: php, forms

Is it possible in php to include a forms value into the action redirection?

For example:

```
<form method='POST' name='Select' action='customer.php?CID=xxxxx'>
<input type=text width='5' name='searchVal' />
```

where xxxxx is the value entered into the form.

I've tried a number of different ways and I'm just not figuring it out! (Still sort of new to php)  Any help would be appreciated.

It was looking like I would have to use $_POST and $_GET.  A little more information might be in order...  customer.php displays a list of customers in order by ID, name, etc.  The user currently clicks on the customer ID that they want to display the details for.  I'm trying to add a box where they can just enter the customer number to get to the details quickly, but I still want to have the listing displayed. From what it is sounding like, I will have to do this as two separate programs...is that true?

Comment: You want to include the value in `CID=` _before_ you post the form, or _after_ posting the form?  Before makes no sense because the value has already been made available in `$_POST` and is redundant in `$_GET`

Comment: After the form is posted.  I want to have a box where they enter the customer ID and when they click the "Go" button it will display the customer's info.

Comment: Do you want to pass a value to your script? Just use a hidden input: `<input type="hidden" name="CID" value="xxxx" />`. It'll be available in your script as `$_POST['CID']`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it finally!  It's actually very simple!

In the body of the code I put this:

```
<form action='#_SELF' method='GET' name='Projected'>
<input type=text size=5 name='CID' value='' title='Enter Customer number to display' />
<a href='#' onclick='document.Projected.submit();' title='Enter Customer number to display'>Go</a>
```

And at the top of the code I just do a:

```
if (!isset($_GET['CID'])) { ...
```

It works exactly the way I wanted it to!

Thanks everyone for the help!  I appreciate it!  (And I'm learning more and more about PHP everyday!)

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
<form method='POST' name='Select' action='customer.php'>
<input type='hidden' value='xxxxx' name='CID' />
<input type=text width='5' name='searchVal' />
...
</form>
```

You are free to add as much hidden values as needed.

Note, that you can even use PHP-like array notation_

```
<input type='hidden' value='xxxxx' name='CID[1]' />
<input type='hidden' value='yyyyy' name='CID[2]' />
```

At the PHP-side, access those values using this syntax:

```
$_POST[ 'CID' ][ 1 ]
$_POST[ 'CID' ][ 2 ]
```

**UPDATE-1**

Ah, you want to use a user-entered values to the Action URL just before the form gets submitted?

In this case you need to use JavaScript. Access the DOM to change the Action URL.

But let me ask, why you need to post a form value additionally as a parameter of the Action URL?

**UPDATE-2**

You wrote: 'From what it is sounding like, I will have to do this as two separate programs...is that true?'

No, actually not. You can still use one `customer.php` which checks at its beginning, if it was called using a linked customer in the table element or a searched customer in the search field.

In other words: You **don't need to prepare two scripts, but two forms** for two purposes which call the same script `customer.php`.

Comment: Ok...so it can't be done right in the php code.  I'll have to write some javascript code to do what I want.  I've added some additional information to me original question that may help explain what I am trying to do.

Comment: I'm still not getting the value that the user enters into the action URL.  If I hardcode a value into the action as a test, it works as expected.  But I just can't figure out how to get the entered value into the action!  Could you possibly give an example of how to do this?  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You can include the required value in a hidden field in your form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="CID" value="xxxxx" />
```

The reason this is required is that you are submitting the form to your server via POST, but appending parameters to the URL requires submission via the GET method.

Answer (score 0):

Not without a post to the server. The value in the form is filled in client-side, so it has to return to the server before you can add it to the `action`. (at least, if you want to use php).

You can either

- add it after posting (might not be usefull)
- use javascript
- just not use the `GET` CID, but get it out of the `POST` in your customer.php script.

Answer (score -1):

Im pretty sure you cant do that unfortunately

Comment: That's what I'm afraid of!  From the reseach I've done it seems like it would be possible, but nothing I've tried will work.

Comment: Actually you can. When this form is submitted form fields will be contained in $_POST and CID will available as $_GET['CID']

Comment: im not quite understanding what you are saying. If you post CID, then its available with $_GET ? to me that doesnt sound right

Comment: @Wilson212 if you post a form using POST method all the form elements will be posted as usual. However if you additionally include a query string for the action URL, PHP will populate $_GET variable with those values. However you are right that you can't alter this value dynamically.

Comment: @Sinan was right!  $_GET worked!  I just needed to get the syntax right.  Thanks for everyone for their help.  I'll post the solution in an answer.